# Нарушение выравнивания полей в профиле

Tags: дефект, дизайн, страница-учётной-записи

При просмотре страницы профиля с мобильного устройства (Android 5.0.2, Chrome 53.0.2785.124), замечено нарушение выравнивания поля ввода для твиттера:

[image: твиттер поехал]